# ZPL command - printed label enumeration

Tags: zpl

is it possible to include in the ZPL command label enumeration to be printed on the label?
For example if I'll be printing 4 labels using ^PQ command, then I would like to have also:

- 1 of 4
- 2 of 4
- 3 of 4
- 4 of 4

printed on the labels.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

I have checked the ZPL manual but couldn't find anything that would help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think about is the ^SN command which can be used to create a counter and print on the label the label number, but as far as I know there's no way to get the printer to print the total number of label of the job.
So you'll have something like
Label 1
Label 2
Label 3
but not the "of 4" part, unless this information is provided by the software which sends the data to print.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This may be our alternative if we can't get the "of 4" part working